# Questions about subscription

Tags: fiware-orion

Suppose the system got a huge number of "sensors".

Block1 makes a subscribeContextRequest to Sensor.* (reference can't be nothing except /callbackOrionNotifyContext/Sensor/.* I guess)

Block2 does a lot of different updateContextRequest to Sensor.N

1. Is there any way to know in reference url which is the number of sensor to have changed? or the best practice to get it immediately without scans?
2. (ONCHANGE scenario) in  I got to put in only the name of an attribute or also kinda like the attribute is equal to X?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. Sorry, the broker doesn't modify the *reference* according to the id of the entity/attribute causing the notification.
   If you really need to see the sensor id in *reference*, you will have to make a separate subscription for each sensor to be treated that way (you say you have a huge number of sensors, so you probably don't want to do this). As I see it, you'll just have to look at the payload.
   And, the *reference* would be e.g. */callbackOrionNotifyContext/SensorX*.
   The *X* you find in the payload.
2. What you describe is contemplated in the spec by OMA and it is the third type of subscriptions, called ONVALUE.
   Orion context broker does not support ONVALUE yet, but it is present on our roadmap. I can't even estimate a date for when it may be supported.

Comment: 2. doesn't really matter now, ONCHANGE can be enough for now.

Comment: 1. not clear yet, sorry. I don't understand if I need to do seperate subscriptions or if there's a workaround when you write "As I see it, ...". Which payload, at which step? Thanks P.S. But I guess you mean my actual solution, making a subscription every time I make the first sensor updateContextRequest in APPEND, am I right?

Comment: 1. What I mean to say is that if you *need* the sensor-id in the path of the **reference**, then you would have to do separate subscriptions for eack sensor.
However, it is probably easier for you to do a single subscription can catch all sensor changes in the same subscription. Doing this, in the payload of the notification you find what sensors have been updated. That is the payload you have to examine - the one of the notification.

Comment: Sorry for bother you but here is exactly what I miss. If I subscribe once (e.g. 1 entity.* with 1 reference), then in my node my notification: app.post(reference, cors(), function(req, res) { ... got info only in req but any payload in it. Is that the notification you're talking about? Appreciate your help.

Comment: Guess I need to have accumulator-server.py for seeing the payload, at least a version in my language.

Comment: At the end it was very easy but for the first time req didn't get to me as usual in node.js. I needed to parse it differently because .body (.data in py) was weirdly empty. I'm seeing the payload now. Thanks

Comment: Oh, you say you don't get any payload in the notification?
That is very strange. All notifications come with payload ...

Comment: Yep, but in node.js the standard express.bodyParser() makes something weird and req.body from Orion seems empty, you gotta get the raw request body instead. Without bodyParser. Now all is ok, thanks.